# column does not exist postgress при попытке добавить запись в таблицу

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

Создаю таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE projects(Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                      Uuid UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
                      Name CHARACTER VARYING(50) NOT NULL, 
                      Created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
                      Updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

И пытаюсь добавить в неё запись через `psycopg2`

```
with psycopg2.connect(dbname=self._db_name, user=self._user,
                          password=self._password, host='localhost') as self._conn:
    with self._conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO projects (Uuid, Name, Created, Updated) VALUES('
                       f'"7e65b2fe-9cb8-4da8-aeb9-0f61f94cb8fd",'
                       f'"proj1",'
                       f'"{datetime.now()}",'
                       f'"{datetime.now()}");')
```

В ответ на попытку добавления записи в таблицу `psycopg2` выдаёт мне следующее

```
column "7e65b2fe-9cb8-4da8-aeb9-0f61f94cb8fd" does not exist
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Видимо из-за двойных кавычек. Текст в двойных кавычках воспринимается как название поля.

Comment: @AlexandrIvanov, если я уберу двойные кавычки вокруг 7e65b2fe-9cb8-4da8-aeb9-0f61f94cb8fd, то выдаётся ошибка syntax error at or near "b2fe"

Comment: Кавычки должны быть одинарными, мне кажется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я в sql понимаю мало, но скорее всего ошибка в кавычках. " " - это указания колонки, а ' ' - это строка. Попробуйте заменить

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO projects (Uuid, Name, Created, Updated) VALUES('
                   f'"7e65b2fe-9cb8-4da8-aeb9-0f61f94cb8fd",'
                   f'"proj1",'
                   f'"{datetime.now()}",'
                   f'"{datetime.now()}");')
```

на

```
cursor.execute(f"""
INSERT INTO projects (Uuid, Name, Created, Updated) 
    VALUES('7e65b2fe-9cb8-4da8-aeb9-0f61f94cb8fd', 'proj1', '{datetime.now()}', '{datetime.now()}')""")
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Крайне редко работаю с sql, уже и забыл, что тут кавычки разные)